# Azure ML: Updating parameters on PipelineDraft created by Designer

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

Just asking around as I could not find any documentation/prior queries on this. I am currently using Azure ML Designer to design a pipeline. I am trying to use the Azure ML Python SDK to modify my `PipelineDraft`—especially the input data used in the `DataSourceNode`; however to no avail.

I have also tried converting it into a parameter and then calling `pipeline.update()`. While this works in changing the `PipelineDraft`'s name, it does not modify any parameters (and thus does not affect the input dataset).

Would really appreciate some help as I have been struggling with this for a while. The SDK documentation is tailored more specifically to Python-only users, as well.

Answer (score 1):

We are sorry to hear this situation. First, for the documentation, I will forward your feedback to content team for more understandable doc.

Second, for the question, I hope the following Python SDK reference helps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.pipeline(class)?view=azure-ml-py

Regards,
Yutong

Comment: OP is asking about PipelineDraft. The link you have provided is for Pipeline. I agree with the OP that azure ml lacks proper documentation with examples. I could not find example of passing parameter in PipelineDraft.

Comment: Sorry, just behind that part is pipedraft's class guidance:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.pipeline_draft.pipelinedraft?view=azure-ml-py